# Taking out random times of a wiener process

Tags: matlab, stochastic-process

First of all I'm new to matlab and this forum so excuse my ignorance.

I generate a standard wiener process in the following way (I made it up myself, so if it's stupid or wrong I would like to know).

```
s =0.0001; % stepsize
t = [0:s:T]; % divide interval into steps

G=sqrt(s)*randn(length(t),1); 

Y=cumsum(G);
```

Now I want to find its values at some random times, say:

```
u=rand(4,1)
```

I figured out (with google and patience) to do something like

```
for i = 1:length(u)
   row(i) = find(t < u(i),1,'last');
end
```

and then simply take out the values from Y, but I would like to find a more direct way - do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're basically doing for each element in `u` is finding the index of the largest element in `t`. Try the following one-liner:

```
sum(bsxfun(@lt, repmat(t(:)', numel(u), 1), u(:)), 2)
```

What this does is:

1. Generate a matrix using `repmat`, where each row equals `t`.
2. Check each row using `bsxfun` for elements less than the corresponding element in `u`.
3. Accumulate all the 1s in each row, essentially giving you the indices of the last smaller elements.

By the way, there is no need to put brackets (`[]`) in `t = [0:s:T]`. The colon operator (`:`) already outputs a vector.

Comment: Perfect, that was that I was looking for! I was hoping to learn a lot of new matlab functions :) I'm off to documentation :D